# Calendar not working on iPhone 4 updated to iOS 7

Tags: icloud, iphone, calendar, ios

I updated my iPhone 4 to iOS 7 and now my calendar is not working. All my entries are gone and it will not allow me to put a new entry in.

My calendar *is* turned on in Settings → iCloud → Calendar, and it was backed up before I updated.

What do I need to do to get my calendar information back?

Comment: It might be an issue with everyone trying to upgrade at once that their servers are getting slammed, though that wouldn't necessarily explain not being able to enter new appointments. What happens when you try?

Comment: Are the entries also missing if you log into https://www.icloud.com through the browser on your computer?

Comment: Same thing here. Restored backup from PC & iCloud but no past calendar entries. There are no entries showing in the iCloud calendar so looks like they just vanished. Am I annoyed - you bet.

Answer (score 1):

If you can log in to https://www.icloud.com and inspect your calendar, that will tell you if the issue is on the server end with missing data (or a failure of your account) or if the phone just can't get a good sync from the server.

The steps to troubleshoot both are a little different, but we'd love you to ask that question once you've figured out where the problem lies.